# The Active Record will auto generate name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I study a e-book of Ruby on Rails:
If I create a Active Record below:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Rails Will execute the below code to generate a table:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
   id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
   name varchar(255),
   PRIMARY KEY  (id)
);
```

There I have a question, I can understand auto generate the major key, but why how to understand the:

```
name varchar(255),
```

If the `name` field is auto generated? and if yes, why it is necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will be auto generate. But it's not a activerecord action, it's related to the database. For mysql, if you doesn't set default value for the column, then it will default be `NULL`, `nil` in ruby.

Even you didn't set value for specific column, it also need to be display in the database, or visit as `product.name`, so do necessary.

Answer (score 0):

No,the sql statement to create the table 'products' is not from your model file(product.rb), but from migrate files.

Where you run a Rails rake command: rake g model product name:sring,
it will not only create a model file(product.rb) for you, but also a migrate file in "db/migrate/" folder, naming like "xxxxxx_create_products.rb". Open this file and you will see lines like:

```
def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :name
    end
end
```

That's how Rails knows what columns you want to have in your "products" talbe, and what type they should be.
And this table will not be created, until you run this command: rake db:migrate.